# TextToSpeech not working in Android 2.2 and 2.3 Phone

Tags: android

What I am doing is I have an EditText and a button. When I write something and press the button, the app speaks those words. This is working fine in Emulator but when I run it on phone, it does not speak. I don't know what is the problem. Is it something with the code or  do I need to change something in the phone. Below is the code that I have used.

```
Button btn1;
EditText txt1;
static final String[] texts={""};
TextToSpeech tts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tts=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            }
        }
    });
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Random r=new Random();
        //String random=texts[r.nextInt(3)];
        String txt=txt1.getText().toString();
        if(txt!="")
        tts.speak(txt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);     
}
```

I checked out the other similar questions but none has a satisfying answer. This is the best place to get technical help. Plz suggest a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. No TTS language was installed on my phone so i did it manually : Settings --> Language and input --> Text to speech output --> Install voice data.

Answer (score 0):

please try

if(!txt.equals(""))
tts.speak(txt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

Also release the tts object after the usage using shutdown() method.

Comment: did not worked. Using this it even doesn't runs on emulator. says - stop() called twice.

Comment: please try this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/